# MVC: Displaying Roles in a list of checkboxes, then saving them

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page where roles are displayed in a list of checkboxes, you can select which roles you want a user to have, and then you click a button to save it.

Here's my model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [DisplayName("Roles")]
    public string[] Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<WebUI.Models.RegisterModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <% foreach(string role in Model.Roles) { %>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<%: role %>" /> <%: role %>
    <% } %>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </p>
<% } %>
```

And the functions from my controller:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //save roles
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

When I try to view my page, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on the foreach statement, signifying that Model.Roles is empty.

1. Am I passing the Roles correctly through my model? Or should I pass the Roles as ViewData through my Controller action?
2. If I pass the Roles as ViewData instead of through my model, how can I access the selected items when I submit the form so that I can call `Roles.AddUsersToRoles()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you are not passing your model to the view when you get the page.  This is causing the null reference exception.  It should be:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register() {

  //create an instance of your model however you are doing that
  var model = new RegisterModel();

  //pass your model instance to your view
  return View(model);
}
```

Second, you need to add a `name` attribute to your inputs in order for the MVC model binding to pass the data when the form is posted.

```
  <% foreach(string role in Model.Roles) { %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Roles" value="<%: role %>" /> <%: role %>
  <% } %>
```

However, as your `Roles` property appears to have no setter you probably should create a view model containing the roles so your code should look like this:

View model

```
public class RegisterViewModel {
  public string[] Roles { get; set; }
  //...other properties
}
```

View

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<WebUI.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
  <% foreach(string role in Model.Roles) { %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Roles" value="<%: role %>" /> <%: role %>
  <% } %>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Register" /></p>
<% } %>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index() {
  var model = new RegisterViewModel();
  model.Roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles(); //or however you populate your roles
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(RegisterViewModel model) {
  string[] roles = model.Roles //the selected roles are here
  //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like ( haven't done this in a while, all from memory ):

```
<% foreach(string role in Model.Roles) { %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="<%: role %>" /> <%: role %>
<% } %>
```

And in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(string[] roles)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //save roles
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

And now for each checked checkbox you'll get a value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but I can explain the null reference exception bit.

You have not created an instance of your RegisterModel class. Your view is expecting a WebUI.Models.RegisterModel, but you have not provided one in this code.

Try either:

`public ActionResult Register() { return View(new RegisterModel()); }`

or make your Roles property static:

`public static string[] Roles`

And access in your view this way:

`foreach(string role in RegisterModel.Roles)`

Answer (score 0):

For testability and sanity, I would change your model to not reach out and try and grab the roles directly but rather take a list of roles in the constructor.